# Tkinter: Instatiate Object with Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am messing around with `tkinter` in Python 3.3 and was wondering how would I go about using/creating an object with a button. I have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, title):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.title = title

    def print_person(self):
        return self.name, str(self.age), self.title


def hello(lbl, nm):
    lbl.config(text="Hello, " + nm)


root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)

name_lbl = Label(root, text="Name: ").grid()
name_ent = Entry(root)
name_ent.grid(row=0, column=1)

age_lbl = Label(root, text="Age: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
age_ent = Entry(root)
age_ent.grid(row=1, column=1)

title_lbl = Label(root, text="Title: ").grid(row=2, column=0)
title_ent = Entry(root)
title_ent.grid(row=2, column=1)

hello_lbl = Label(root, text="").grid(row=4, columnspan=2)
btn = Button(root, text="Confirm", command=lambda: Person(name_ent.get(), age_ent.get(), title_ent.get())).grid(row=3, columnspan=2)



root.mainloop()
```

How do I name the object created by clicking the button for later use? For example, how would I use the `print_person()` method on the object created by filling out the entries and clicking the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the Person object using a variable.

For example:

```
...
def create_a_person():
    global person
    person = Person(name_ent.get(), age_ent.get(), title_ent.get())

Button(root, text="Confirm", command=create_a_person).grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
Button(root, text="Print", command=lambda: print(person.print_person())).grid(row=4, columnspan=2)
...
```

---

BTW, `grid` method returns `None`.

```
hello_lbl = Label(root, text="").grid(row=4, columnspan=2) # => None
```

If you want `Label` objected to be saved, you should use following form:

```
hello_lbl = Label(root, text="")
hello_lbl.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: Are there any dangers/concerns I should watch out for using a global variable?

Comment: @IanAuld, Any function can change `person` global variable. In addition to that if confirm button is clicked multiple times, only the last Person is kept. ; Any problem that can be caused by global variable can happend here. (I used global variable to simplify the answer code.)